# How to find a range of records using sails-filemaker?

Tags: sails.js, filemaker

I'm having problems using the find criteria or the where criteria with sails-filemaker. According to what I've read in the sails documentation I'm using the correct criteria. The work around I'm using is to not use the find or where criteria and to remove the records after the find. Ok for very small record sets but it's not elegant.

```
var staffCriteriaFind = {roleId:[1,2]} ;
var staffCriteriaWhere = {or:[{roleID:1},{roleId:2}]} ;

Staff.find().where().exec(function(error,staff){
    /* remove staff members who are not account managers or artists */
    for ( index = staff.length-1; index > 0; index--) {
        var staffMember = staff[index];
        if ( staffCriteriaFind.roleId.indexOf( staffMember.roleId ) == -1 ) {
            staff.splice([index],1) ;
        }
    }
    result.staff = staff ;
    return res.send(responseCode, result ) ;    
});
```

The staff model is

```
/**
* Staff.js
*
* @description :: Staff employed by the business
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

    connection: 'filemaker',
    tableName: 'staff-list-api-layout',

    autoPK:false ,
    autoCreatedAt: false ,
    autoUpdatedAt: false ,

  attributes: {
        id: {
            columnName: 'staff_id_',
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true,
            unique:true
        } , 
        role:{
            columnName:'staff_role::role',
            type: 'string'
        },
        timesheetSort:{
            columnName:'staff_role::timesheet_sort',
            type:'string'
        },
        roleId:{
            columnName: 'role_id',
            type: 'integer',
            foreignKey: true
        },
        name:{
            columnName:'full_name',
            type: 'string'
        },
        createdAt:{
            type:'date'
        },
        updatedAt:{
            type:'date'
        }
  }

};
```

If I use

```
var staffCriteriaFind = {roleId:[1,2]} ;
var staffCriteriaWhere = {or:[{roleID:1},{roleId:2}]} ;

Staff.find(staffCriteriaFind).where().exec(function(error,staff){
    result.staff = staff ;
    return res.send(responseCode, result ) ;    
});
```

I get all staff members with roleId = 1 and none with roleId = 2.

If I use

```
var staffCriteriaFind = {roleId:[1,2]} ;
var staffCriteriaWhere = {or:[{roleID:1},{roleId:2}]} ;

Staff.find().where(staffCriteriaWhere).exec(function(error,staff){
    result.staff = staff ;
    return res.send(responseCode, result ) ;    
});
```

I get no staff records at all ...

What is the correct way to use a findCriteria or a whereCriteria with sails-filemaker where an or search across a range of values is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a filemaker script, passed in the parameters to that script and then extracted the roleId's to execute a find within filemaker instead.

```
var staffCriteria = {
                          'staff_id_' : '>0',
                          '-script' : 'find-staff-api-script',
                          '-script.param' : '{roleId:[1,2]}'
                    };
                    Staff.find(staffCriteria).where().exec(function(error,staff){

                        if ( error ) {
                            result.error = error ;
                            result.staffCriteria = staffCriteria ;
                        }
                        result.staff = staff ;
                        return res.send(responseCode, result ) ;    
                    });
```

see https://gist.github.com/toddgeist/13157485b81f3e2b985e for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

After much messing around, I've found you can use Filemakers range terminology '...' in the find function.

```js
staff.find({ a_StaffID: '1...12', position: '100...400' })
.then('do whatever you need to do with the returned data')
.catch('do whatever you need to do with any error')
```

Answer (score 0):

Todd Geist would be the best person to ask, but I can try to guess

Your Staff.find is probably uses FileMaker Find functionality so it can only find one parameter at a time. Try to use {roleId:[2,1]} instead, you will probably get all roleId = 1

The problem is, I can't find find().where anywhere in sales-filemaker. I think you are looking at  newFindRequest(fmLayout, options.where) where it is a parameter and not the method.

Try staff.find(staffCriteriaWhere), this might work

Comment: staff.find(staffCriteriaWhere) failed. I ended up using a script.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, **where** is sails method, not sales-filemaker.

I think you should try this:

```
Staff.find().where({roleId:1 },{roleId:2 })
```

or

```
Staff.find().where({roleId:1 }).where({roleId:2 })
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolai. That failed to work but I appreciate your insight.